# OPA how to reuse Javascript and Node.js packages

Tags: node.js, opa

So I read the article of 12 jan 2012 on how to include existing javascript packages as a plugin in Opa: http://blog.opalang.org/2012/01/reusing-javascript-libraries-jquery-ui.html

However in the announcement for [OPA 1.1.0 it states on feb 12 2013](http://blog.opalang.org/2013/02/some-great-news-on-opa.html):

> "With Opa 1.1.0, you now can include JavaScript code and Node.js
>   packages easier than ever! We will write about it soon."

So I would like to inlcude some Node.js packages (an SDK), questions what is the new easy method of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you had to prepare special file with JS values exported to Opa tagged with special annotations like:

```
##register value_name : type_of_arg1, type_of_arg2 -> void
##args(arg1, arg2)
{
  run_someJS_code();
}
```

The file had to be compiled to the package with special tool and then usable in Opa with `%%Filename.value_name%%(x,y)`.

Now tagging of JS values with Opa types and marking them for export to Opa is inside JS source files in comment syntax `/** */`. The files are still valid JS files, so you can update existing JS files in place. They also do not require special tool to compile them. Standard Opa compiler accept JS files as any other Opa file and understands annotations in comments. As before, you link the client JS and server Node.js code exactly the same way.

Unfortunately, as most of the advanced Opa feature is poorly documented and you have to read the standard library sources to learn it. Basic functionality as available like this:

bslLeaflet.js:

```
// These are the native JS "types" that will be available in Opa
/** @externType leaflet_map */
/**
 * @register {string, float, float, int, bool, bool -> leaflet_map}
 */
function leafletMap(id, center_lat, center_lon, zoom, zoomControl, attributionControl) {
  return L.map(id, {center:[center_lat, center_lon], zoom:zoom, zoomControl:zoomControl, attributionControl:attributionControl});
}
```

myMap.opa:

```
type leaflet_map = external
leaflet_map map = %%BslLeaflet.leafletMap%%("my_map_id", lat, lon, 14, true, true)
```

Although doing simple things as now very easy and quick, to learn things like:

- running JS function with continuations,
- using Opa types in JS (can you use custom Opa records?),
- using arguments of list type (is translation from Opa's `{hd,tl} or {nil}` to JS list performed automatically like Opa `bool={true} or {false}` to JS `boolean`?),
- running Opa functions passed as arguments to JS functions,

requires some experimenting. If you will manage to understand some of it, write something about it because I will really be glad to learn it too :)

Comment: Thanks. Probably have a lot more questions, before I can answer some. Have started a blog http://wouterzanen.tumblr.com. To share my experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time to figure out the answers to 3 of [Marcins questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18277086/1045983) so I will share them here:

- > using Opa types in JS (can you use custom Opa records?)

yes, it's possible. Use "@opaType". Let's assume you defined **Model.graph** in some opa file

```
/**
 * @opaType Model.graph
 */
/**
 * @register {Model.graph -> void}
 */
function render(g) { ... }
```

- > using arguments of list type (is translation from Opa's {hd,tl} or {nil} to JS list performed automatically like Opa bool={true} or {false} to JS boolean?)

no, there is no translation for lists (maybe because of performance?). The javascript representation of a opa list:

```
{hd: {a: "1"}, tl: {hd: {a: "2"}, tl: {nil: {}}}}
```

- > running Opa functions passed as arguments to JS functions

that's possible again:

```
/**
 * @register {string, (string -> void) -> void}
 */
function call_me_back(number, callback) {
  callback(number);
}
```

Comment: For the second point (using Opa lists in JS), Opa provides some small utility functions converting between Opa lists and JS arrays: list2js, js2list and also similar function for converting between option('a) and JS nullable value: option2js and js2option.